# Installshield Setup/Patch/Upgrade question

Tags: installation, upgrade, installshield, patch

I hope someone can answer my questions. I made an installer using Installshield. Then also about 5 patches because of some bugs and everything. Now here are my questions:

1. Is it possible to make new
   installer based on the previous one,
   like an upgrade, but with the
   patched file on it and not the
   original files?
2. Supposed that question 1 is
   possible, and then I made another
   patch based on the new installer.
   But then, a user who is using the
   previous installer installed in his
   computer downloaded the patch
   based on the new installer and
   installed it. Is it a valid patch
   also because the new installer is
   based on the previous one?

Please note that I am not an installshield master and I would be thankful if someone could answer my questions or give some helpful links.

Answer (score 1):

This is really advanced stuff, but there's no better source than the Windows Installer documentation:
[Patching and Upgrades](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370579%28VS.85%29.aspx)

[Patching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370578%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When to do what (i.e. Upgrade vs. Update vs. Patch) is best explained by InstallShield [here](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield18helplib/MajorMinorSmall.htm). Based on the facts mentioned in the table describing when to implement which type of update, one should decide if it is an upgrade or update or patch.

Upgrades can be of two types, to keep previous installation as it is and have another installation side by side (which may be conflicting and hard to manage), another one is to remove previous installation automatically before installing the newer one. So, your first question upgrade is possible, you need to decide which type.

For second question, while creating patch you can create an [InstallCondition](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/IHelpProdCondition.htm) to check for previous installed versions exists and decide accordingly what needs to be done.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming there is a source control system in place, when a product (in this case installer version1) is released.

The Release Engineer would take a snap-shot of the state of the "Release Branch" and then rename it accordingly for the next release (Installer Version2 in this case).

Developers would continue to code in a similar branch (Dev branch) which has the same bits until the release date.

From this "Release/Dev" branch a HotFixes/Patches branch is created and patches are released from a "Hot Fixes or Patches" branch.

These patches would contain logic that would determine the pre-reqs for installation.  For instance "patch1-version1" would require "Release version1" ... "patch2-version1" would require maybe just "patch1-version1"... etc.

When you are ready to create a second release "Release Version2", the Release Branch would be named accordingly and would have all the changes from "Release Version1" + "All fixes" in the "Hot Fixes or Patches" branch.

This new release would need logic to uninstall the previous release and install the new one.

NOW, a new "Hot Fixes" branch is created from the up-to-date "Release Branch" or the changes are simply brought down to the previously created "Hot fixes" branch and any new patches for "Release Version2" should now have updated logic to ONLY allow installation on the new requirements... those pertaining to "Release Version2".

For example, "Patch1-ReleaseVersion2" would require the presence of "Release Version2" ... similarly "Patch2-ReleaseVersion2" would probably required both "Release Version2" plus the first patch released or simply the presence of the first patch released, because the base release (Release Version2) must also be there.

So, given this standard, "patch1,2,3...n-ReleaseVersion2" should never install on any server which has "Release Version1" +  Zero/More patches, because the logic in the patch installer would not (or should not) allow such thing.